# How to modify how the_content outputs a link to an internal page

Tags: hooks, the-content

I like the default add link dialog in the wordpress editor.  IT allows for easy linking to internal pages.  I need to modify the output of those internal links.

Right now its outputting:

```
<a href="page url" title="linked page title">my text</a>
```

I need it to be:

```
<a href="page url" title="linked page title" data-id="linked page id">my text</a>
```

I need the linked page id to be set in a data attr. Is this possible with a action/hook

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm in a hurry so don't have time to provide any code, pseudo or otherwise, but you could probably do this in the `the_content` filter by using a regex to find all links and for each one find the page/post ID using `url_to_postid` and then replacing as appropriate.

Good luck!

Comment: This makes sense, how much a performance hit will I take?

Comment: Good question, that I don't know the answer to. The regex itself should be negligible, but the other function is probably a db query each time, so a page with lots of links could hammer the database a bit.

Comment: Got it.  Its a functional answer to the question.